# How to add up numbers found by comparing dates and company?

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, worksheet-function

[image: example screenshot]

```
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| Date      | Company | Payment |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 1/15/2016 | Acme    | $128.00 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 1/14/2016 | Pixar   | $72.60  |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/14/2015 | NBA     | $410.85 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/14/2015 | Uber    | $217.30 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/13/2015 | Acme    | $132.00 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/13/2015 | Acme    | $290.40 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/10/2015 | NBA     | $537.60 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/10/2015 | Acme    | $355.58 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/8/2015  | Acme    | $103.13 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/7/2015  | NBA     | $115.00 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/7/2015  | Uber    | $211.20 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/5/2015  | Acme    | $412.50 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/5/2015  | Uber    | $275.00 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 5/5/2015  | NBA     | $128.00 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 4/30/2015 | NBA     | $72.60  |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 4/30/2015 | Acme    | $410.85 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 4/30/2015 | Acme    | $217.30 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 4/29/2015 | Uber    | $132.00 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 4/29/2015 | Pixar   | $290.40 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 4/27/2015 | Uber    | $537.60 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
| 4/27/2015 | Acme    | $355.58 |  |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+--+
```

I need to add up the payments made by each company in each month (the data is spread over 2 years). So for this example I need to use Excel to find when Acme paid in May, and add all of those payments up. Same for the others. I'm kind of inexperienced, and haven't been able to find a good example of someone doing this in the past.

Output needs to be in a different sheet, ideally organized like this:

```
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | January        | 2015 |  $ 110.00       |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | February       | 2015 |  $   35.00      |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | March          | 2015 |  $   33.00      |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | April          | 2015 |  $          -   |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | May            | 2015 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | June           | 2015 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | July           | 2015 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | August         | 2015 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | September      | 2015 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | October        | 2015 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | November       | 2015 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | December       | 2015 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | TOTAL for 2015 |      |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | January        | 2016 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | February       | 2016 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | March          | 2016 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | April          | 2016 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | May            | 2016 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | June           | 2016 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | July           | 2016 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | August         | 2016 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | September      | 2016 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | October        | 2016 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | November       | 2016 |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | December       | 2016 |                 |   
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+  
| Acme | TOTAL for 2016 |      |                 |  
+------+----------------+------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Do you need to do this on a repeating basis and so want to write a macro, or do you simply need the values today? Also, is this a homework problem you're asking for assistance with?

Comment: It's easier for people to develop and verify solutions if you provide sample data rather than a picture of data.  You can use a web resource like http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables or https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/ to easily convert a spreadsheet snippet to a text table that you can paste in the question.

Comment: Look into SUMIFS() ,  It will do what you want.  You will need to set the criteria of greater or equal to the first of the month and less than or equal to the end of the month.

Comment: I added text tables that should help with what everyone is asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give no information as to the appearance of your results.  But one possibility is to use a Pivot Table.

- Drag dates to the rows area
- Companies to the columns area
- Payment to the values area
- Group dates by Years and Months
- Format as you like.

Here is an example of those results

[image]

You have edited your post to show how you would like the outputs.  If you drag the company to the Rows area, and arrange things so Company is first in that list, the output becomes close to what you show:

[image]

And the Subtotals and Grand Totals are easily removed in the Design tab

[image]

If this is an infrequent task, you can easily do this manually.  If it is something that needs to be done several times a day, a macro might be a better way to go, if you can familiarize yourself with VBA.

Comment: Can I do this with different sheets?

Comment: @Jthelp Not sure what you mean exactly.  You can insert a Pivot table on a different worksheet.  Then you can either update that pivot table, or create a new one on a different sheet.  You can use slicers or filters to display a limited subset.  I suggest you read about pivot tables so as to use them most effectively for your purposes. Plenty of references on the 'net.

Comment: @Jthelp  I'll add a screen shot showing the results formatted closer to what you show in your example

Comment: @Jthelp One other thing, not sure of relevance.  If you drag the company to the Filter area, you can then, under Pivot TAble Options, select to `Show Filter Report Pages`. This will instantly generate a separate worksheet for each Company, with the Worksheet Tab being Named by the company

Comment: How did you set up the dates? I can't seem to convert my dates into the format shown in your answer.

Comment: @Jthelp When you select to `Group` by `Months` and `Years`, what I showed should be what you get.  And you may want to try the different `Report Layout` options.  I chose `Tabular Form`, and `Repeat all labels`, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Would it be possible to add similar data (companies, dates, costs) to the same pivot table from a different source? Its a separate sheet

Comment: @Jthelp Of course. If you have not done my suggested internet search regarding pivot tables, I would suggest starting with Microsoft Office Support [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=20428&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)